# Can't seem to decrease column width in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a layout in bootstrap that has a single column in the center. The problem I'm having is that even after setting the column width by using class="col-sm-3" (or something similar), it stays the same size. Ideally I would like the width of the row to be the same as the image in the code below.

Tried to use col-sm-x classes, didn't work. Basically I want no white space around the 300x50 image below.

```
<div class="container rounded" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <center><img src="window_top_logo.jpg" width="300" height="50"></center>
                </div>
        </div>


</div>
```

Basically I want no white space around the 300x50 image below.

Comment: Was able to sort of fix it by setting the CSS width property of the container to 300px, the problem with that is that there's this small part of the image that goes past the rounded corners. Anyone know how to contain it so that it's within the rounded corners?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `col-sm-12` and use your own css to position it.

```css
.image_container {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container rounded" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <div class="image_container">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x50" width="300" height="50">
                      </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```